# How to defeat mac address filtering on a wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, mac-address

This question concerns a wifi router that has MAC address filtering enabled. For reasons beyond the scope of the question, the filtering can't be disabled. I have access to the router and can manually add MAC addresses, but doing so is laborious.

I'm seeking a way to add multiple devices to the network without having to manually enter the MAC address of each.

Is there any way to do this? For example, is it possible to use some sort of "wifi booster" which could connect to the network, which arbitrary devices could connect to, and which could then filter traffic from the new devices through its own MAC address?

Comment: I wonder if you could set some sort of WiFi extender that connects to his network, but also lets you create one in your flat? Might need to be a full on router.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  Ok, edited.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Sub-leasing an internet connection is perfectly legal in many jurisdictions.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas, perfectly legal in just about every country. It may however be against the ISP terms of service...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is by having another WIFI/Wired router (which then you can use stronger encryption methods, or whatever) and connect this router to the mac-filtered one. You'd then just need to add the MAC of that router to the other one and connect any device you want to the second router.

All traffic coming to the remote router, assuming you are using its dedicated WAN port (or wireless dedicated client port) will be presented only with the "new" router, whilst you will have full management access to it.

Then you may be asking yourself: Why you can't just have all devices directly to it with the same MAC address? This address is a lower-than-IP level layer for local network communication. The MAC address is equivalent to the IP address (192.168.1.2 for example) when locating devices in the immediately local network (which usually share the same IP address range).

If two devices in the same physical network have the same MAC address, they will be receiving data at the same time no matter which one is the target for that packet of data.

At first, one could think it could work, because while both parties are receiving datagrams, each one will receive a datagram encapsulating a IP address they have, so they could just discard the packet if not addressed to their IP address and use the ones for them.

This does not work in practice for, at least, two reasons:

1. both nodes will be replying CRC (cyclic redundancy check) that validate whether a packet was sent successfully, so the check will be, at least, erractic
2. a IP packet is 'upper' in spite to 'ethernet', keyword 'encapsulating' above means it: a single IP packet is encapsulated in one, or several ethernet datagrams. This means there's no guarantee, from a sequence of ethernet datagrams, one IP packet can be built, and then CRC on upper level (IP) will most likely fail, for opening a packet for a given IP and receiving parts of the packet to another -- or simply opening the packet to two different IPs without closing the previous one, and all sorts of inconsistencies.

If you have a router behind it (as suggested in the beginning), it will then coordinate the packets, sending all data as a single MAC (and IP address if you're enabling NAT -- network address translation), and translating them back to the clients on "the other side" of the router (that's what a router means anyway).

Comment: You may be able to Mac clone the whitelisted Mac to the wan interface of the new router. I think this is the best solution for the question asked. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just add some MAC addresses of your choice to the whitelist, like:

```
DE:AD:BE:EF:FF:01
DE:AD:BE:EF:FF:02
DE:AD:BE:EF:FF:03
...
```

If you got a new device (e.g. a PC running GNU/Linux Debian), just pick one (unused) MAC address and set it as the device's new MAC address:

[image: Set MAC address on GNU/Linux Debian 10]

Or on Windows 10:

[image: Set MAC address on Windows 10]

Answer (score 0):

You need the log in name and password to the router so you can add the MAC addresses you need. You friend needs to permit this. Alternatively, your friend would have to add the addresses upon demand. Access to the router is needed for this activity

Comment: Would setting up a proxy avoid the necessity (i.e., the neighbor allows the MAC address for the proxy, and the querent has all of his other devices connect through that proxy device)? If so, what are the possible penalties relative to speed?

Comment: That is somewhat weak as the friend still needs to provide so some access to the MAC settings

Comment: Another thought is to remove MAC filtering (it has limits) and greatly increase the wireless security to keep out intruders

Comment: @John MAC filtering does not increase security at all. MAC addresses are always transmitted unencrypted. An attacker is able to eavesdrop whitelisted MAC addresses and impersonate them.

Comment: My comment was to increase wireless security to keep intruders out. People use MAC filtering to try to limit access.

Comment: MAC filtering is the digital equivalent of posting a sign beside your door reading "Dear intruder, please do not break into my house *twinkle smiley*". You can do that. It does not improve security at all.